# Given the probability find y for gamma distribution

Tags: r

Looking for some assistance using r. I know that there is `invgamma` but I am not sure if that will work/how to use it correctly. If `X` has a Gamma distribution with shape parameter `r = 3` and scale parameter `ρ = 6` is there a way to calculate `y` such that Prob(X < y) = .95?  thanks!

Comment: `qgamma(0.95, 3, scale = 6)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `R` you have 4 types of functions for distribution:

- r[*name of the distribution*]- Random number generator
- q[*name of the distribution*]- Quantile function
- d[*name of the distribution*]- Density function
- p[*name of the distribution*]- Distribution function

So since you have the probability, you need yo use `qgamma`.

#### P(X < x) = 0.95

```
shape <- 3
rate <- 6
x_95 <- qgamma(p = 0.95,shape = shape, rate = rate)

[1] 1.049299
```

[image]

### Plot code

```
df <-
  tibble(
    x = seq(0,3,l = 1000)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(y = dgamma(x = x,shape = shape,rate = rate))


ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_function(fun = dgamma, args = list(shape = shape, rate = rate))+
  geom_vline(xintercept = x_95, linetype = "dashed")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = x_95)+
  geom_area(data = df %>% filter(x <= x_95),
            alpha = .7, fill = "chocolate2")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))+
  annotate(geom = "text",x = .5,y = .7,label = "95%",size = 12)
```